# Ckeditor image alignment remove

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor for my textarea. It works great, but I don't need the image alignment option. How do I remove it?
Here is the image.js file in which I guess you can change that, but I am not that good with javascript!
http://pastebin.com/ZX2ECECp

Comment: what have you tried? don't just post/link to a wall of text, try something instead, then we can help you :D

Comment: I have tried to remove everything from {id:"cmbAlign", till }
And that messed image up! Like I said I am not good with javascript so I really don't know what to do and what not!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using CKEditor 4.4+ then this will work:

```
config.disallowedContent = 'img{float}';
```

Read more in the [Disallowed Content guide](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_disallowed_content).